# What is a better way to prove the identity: $\frac{1}{x} = \log_{x^x}(x)$ where $x>0$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

This is my attempt at an algebraic proof of the identity $\frac{1}{x} = \log_{x^x}(x)$ where $x>0$:
$$ \text{Let} \space n = \log_{x^x}(x)\space \text{where} \space x>0 $$
$$\log_{x^x}(x)=n$$
$$(x^x)^n=x$$
$$\ln((x^x)^n)=\ln(x)$$
$$xn\cdot \ln(x)=\ln(x)$$
$$xn=1$$
$$n=\frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: Hint: Base change formula. $$\log_{x^x}(x) =\frac{\log(x)}{\log (x^x)}$$

Comment: Your proof is correct, and a "better way" (? at least shorter) is to use [What does $ \log_a (b) $ equal to?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756329/what-does-log-a-b-equal-to). More generaly, [$\log_{a^n}(a^m) = \frac{m}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1115876/386889).